# Selenium get .har file

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob

I have a two page application:

**/login**

**/profile**

I want to get .har file page **/profile**.

When i go to the page **/login**, the cookie is created with a key=connect.sid and value = "example value". This cookie is not yet active.
I added the cookies with active connect.sid.

```
WebDriver webDriver = getDriver();
webDriver.get(LOGIN_PAGE);
webDriver.manage().addCookie(connectsSId);
```

it does not work because after the load page, /login crated a new cookies. 
i also tried this code:

```
WebDriver webDriver = getDriver();
webDriver.get(PROFILE_PAGE);
webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
webDriver.manage().addCookie(connectsSId);
```

and this does not work. cookies were added but it seems too late.

```
 WebDriver webDriver = getDriver();
 LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(getDriver());
 LandingPage landingPage = loginPage.login();
 landingPage.openProfilePage();
```

This code created a .har file for the page **/login**.

for some reason, the file is created only after the first call to the page. I can not solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use PhantomJS with BrowserMobProxy. PhantomJS helps us for JavaScript enables pages. The following code works for HTTPS web addresses, too.

Place **'phantomjs.exe'** in C drive and you get the **'HAR-Information.har'** file in C drive itself.

Make sure you **DO NOT** put a **' / '** at the end of the url, like

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
```

It should be

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

Otherwise, it won't work.

```
package makemyhar;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy;
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer;
import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.Har;
import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MakeMyHAR {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        //BrowserMobProxy
        BrowserMobProxy server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        server.start(0);
        server.setHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.getAllContentCaptureTypes());
        server.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
        server.newHar("Google");

        //PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS
        ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<>();
        cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=localhost:"+server.getPort());
        cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");

        //DesiredCapabilities
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\\phantomjs.exe");

        //WebDriver
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        //HAR
        Har har = server.getHar();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\HAR-Information.har");
        har.writeTo(fos);
        server.stop();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set preferences in your Selenium code:

```
    profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.enableAutoExportToFile", true);
profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.defaultLogDir", String.valueOf(dir));
profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.defaultFileName", "network-log-file-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S");
```

and open console:

```
Actions keyAction = new Actions(driver);
keyAction.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).sendKeys("q").keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).perform();
```

Comment: That looks like a very attractive solution.  But how do I get to the profile from the driver?
E.g.:
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

Comment: @creathor : according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611579/how-to-set-preferences-for-chrome-in-selenium-python  It seems that preferences are Firefox feature and chrome use options instead. This answer seems to be Firefox specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use browsermob proxy to capture all the request and response data
[See here](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried as well to get the har file using a proxy like browsermob proxy

I did a lot of research because the file which I've received was always empty.

What I did was to enable the browser performance log.

Note this will work only with chrome driver.

This is my driver class (in python)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver
from lib.config import config


class Driver:

    global performance_log
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Nexus 5"}

    if config.Env().is_mobile():
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
            "mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    else:
        pass

    chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
        'perfLoggingPrefs', {"enablePage": True})

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=self.chrome_options)

    def navigate(self, url):
        if isinstance(url, str):
            self.instance.get(url)
            self.performance_log = self.instance.get_log('performance')
        else:
            raise TypeError("URL must be a string.")
```

The amount of information which is found the in output is huge so you'll have to filter the raw data and get the network received and send objects only.

```
import json
import secrets


def digest_log_data(performance_log):
    # write all raw data in a file
    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        json.dump(performance_log, outfile)
    # open the file and real it with encoding='utf-8'
    with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        data = json.loads(data_file.read())
        return data


def digest_raw_data(data, mongo_object={}):
    for idx, val in enumerate(data):
        data_object = json.loads(data[idx]['message'])
        if (data_object['message']['method'] == 'Network.responseReceived') or (data_object['message']['method'] == 'Network.requestWillBeSent'):
            mongo_object[secrets.token_hex(30)] = data_object
        else:
            pass
```

We choose to push this data into a mongo db which will be analyse later by an etl and pushed into a redshift database to create statistics .

I hope is what you are looking for.

The way Im running the script is :

```
import codecs
from pprint import pprint
import urllib
from lib import mongo_client
from lib.test_data import test_data as data
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
from IPython import embed
from lib.output_data import process_output_data as output_data
from lib.config import config
from lib import driver

browser = driver.Driver()

# get the list of urls which we need to navigate
urls = data.url_list()

for url in urls:
    browser.navigate(config.Env().base_url() + url)
    print('Visiting ' + url)
    # get performance log
    performance_log = browser.performance_log
    # digest the performace log
    data = output_data.digest_log_data(performance_log)
    # initiate an empty dict
    mongo_object = {}
    # prepare the data for the mongo document
    output_data.digest_raw_data(data, mongo_object)
    # load data into the mongo db
    mongo_client.populate_mongo(mongo_object)


browser.instance.quit()
```

My main source was this one which I've adjusted it to my needs.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/97m9iq/headless_browsers_export_to_har/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by the simplest way Selenide + Java + JS
import java.nio.file.Files and java.nio.file.Paths in you class
Then create function:

```
public static void getHar() {
open("http://you-task.com");
String scriptGetInfo = "performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(1000000);" +
                              "return performance.getEntriesByType('resource').map(JSON.stringify).join('\\n')";
String har = executeJavaScript(scriptGetInfo);
Files.write(Paths.get("log.har"), har.getBytes());
}
```

It saves you log.har in the root of you project.
Just call this function in the place you want to save har-file