# How to set preferences for Chrome in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am able to set preferences for Firefox as below.

```
set_preference = profile.set_preference
set_preference("network.http.response.timeout", 30)
set_preference("media.autoplay.enabled", False)
set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
set_preference("network.proxy.type", 2)
set_preference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", pac_url)
set_preference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url.include_path", True)
```

But I need to setup for Chrome as well.. Can any one assist me how to do ?

Thanks Hafsa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Chrome, I think you are looking for `ChromeOptions` here. You can add `prefs` to the `ChromeOptions`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--headless")
# etc...

# declare prefs
prefs = {"media.autoplay.enabled" : False, "network.proxy.autoconfig_url" : pac_url, "network.proxy.autoconfig_url.include_path" : True}

# add prefs 
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```